# Caffe: classifier with probabilistic output greater than 1

Tags: neural-network, caffe, pycaffe, conv-neural-network

I am trying to run Caffe on cifar-10 data using python. This is the end of my proto.txt (note: my deploy file does not have loss layer!)

```
...
layer {
  name: "ampl"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "maxPool1"
  top: "ampl"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 10
    bias_term: false
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.2
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "Softmax"
  bottom: "ampl"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "loss"
}
```

But when I look at my output probabilities, they are not [0 1].
This is also how I read my output label in test phase:

```
net = caffe.Net(modelFile, weightsFile, caffe.TEST)

# estimate amplitude
shape = (data.shape[0], net.blobs['ampl'].data.shape[1])
dtype = net.blobs['ampl'].data.dtype

aE = np.ndarray(shape,dtype)

for i in range(data.shape[0]):
    net.blobs['data'].data[...] = data[i].reshape(net.blobs['data'].data.shape)
    net.forward()
    aE[i,:] = net.blobs['ampl'].data
```

This is the output for first 5 samples:

```
   -0.8576         0         0         0   -1.2853
   -1.1855         0         0         0   -0.3572
   -2.2088         0         0         0   -2.6844
   -1.2650         0         0         0   -3.8973
   -1.2844         0         0         0   -3.8011
   -1.5247         0         0         0   -3.9778
   -1.6097         0         0         0   -3.7351
   -1.0909         0         0         0   -3.6270
   -1.3660         0         0         0   -0.4569
   -1.0892         0         0         0   -0.2500
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are outputting the "ampl" layer, which is a fully connected layer, only softmax will produce actual probabilities so you should output the layer that contains the softmax operation (without the loss, just softmax).

You could also output the last layer and apply softmax manually.

Comment: should i add another layer as "softmax" or the current loss layer type="softmax" can be used?

Comment: @NimaHatami Actually what you have is not a loss layer, its just a softmax, you can use that one as output directly.

Comment: do I need to add this softmax also to deploy? also, do i need to add a loss layer? if yes, to proto or deploy or both? thanks

Comment: @NimaHatami Yes, no. I think the confusion comes that SoftmaxWithLoss is usually used, which combines softmax and cross-entropy loss, but to actually use the model in deploy, you need to use softmax without the loss.

Comment: so if i understand correctly i do not need any loss layer in any of deploy or proto. so how BP will calculate loss?

Comment: No, you need a loss layer for training, but not to deploy.